# How can I convert a Two D string array to One D string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a two dimensional string array:

```
String myTwoD[][] = {{"Apple", "Banana"}, {"Pork", "Beef"}, {"red", 
"green","blue","yellow"}};
```

How do I convert this to a one dimensional string array as follows in JAVA:

```
OneD[]={"Apple", "Banana","Pork", "Beef","red", "green","blue","yellow"};
```

Can ArrayUtils be used for this?

Here is the code for my array, I am trying to store all values in a multipage table column to an array for sorting

```
for (i=0;i<pagecount; i++)
  {
  for (j=0;j<columncount;j++)
   {
    array[i][j]= t.getcolumnname().get(j).getText();
   }
  }
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(myTwoD).flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(String[]::new)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways of how you can do it, one way can be first storing the contents of your 2D array to a list and then using it to store the elements in your new 1D array.

In code it looks something like this:

```java
//arr being your old array

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {  
            list.add(arr[i][j]); 
        }
    }

    // now you need to add it to new array


    String[] newArray = new String[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = list.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. Will this work for string? @PradyumanDixit

Comment: @SUPARNASOMAN try the updated code

Comment: It is showing null values in the array now @PradyumanDixit

Comment: Which array is showing null values? `newArray` must be having the values of your previous array.

Comment: Can you show the exact code you're using for this, right now, because this code is and should be working. I can look into your code and tell what may have gone wrong.

Comment: Hi I have updated the code, I am trying to store all the values of one column from a multipage table to an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182979/discussion-between-pradyumandixit-and-suparna-soman).

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Comment: If you found the answer useful consider upvoting it and marking it as correct, I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I found out is using stream.

```
String myTwoD[][] = { { "Apple", "Banana" }, { "Pork", "Beef" }, { "red", "green", "blue", "yellow" } };
List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(myTwoD);

list.stream().flatMap(num -> Stream.of(num)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

To store the result into a 1D array. Do this:

```
String arr[] = list.stream().flatMap(num -> Stream.of(num)).toArray(String[]::new);

for (String s : arr) {
   System.out.println("Array is = " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
String myTwoD[][] = {{"Apple", "Banana"}, {"Pork", "Beef"},{"red", "green","blue","yellow"}};

    List<String> lt = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String[] oneDArray : myTwoD) { //loop throug rows only
        lt.addAll(Arrays.asList(oneDArray));
    }

    String[] oneDArray =(String[])lt.toArray(new String[0]); //conversion of list to array      
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneDArray)); //code for printing array
```